# Restoring .mkd file to Pervasive SQL

Tags: pervasive-sql

I want to restore or attach .MKD file to Pervasive SQL. I only have the .MKD file and want to restore it to Pervasive SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your application requires DDF files, there is no "restoring" or "attaching" an MKD to a PSQL database.
The MKD file can be opened by the PSQL engine directly.
Simply point your application to the MKD file and it should be fine.

Comment: I am new to PSQL. Can you please a little bit elaborate how I can open the MKD file directly? Which application I am pointing to MKD file? Good if you can include screenshot or steps to implement.

Comment: Where did your MKD file come from?  That's the application that you can use to open the file directly.  What version of PSQL are you using?
  PSQL is a database  like Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL.  If you have DDFs (FILE.DDF, FIELD.DDF, INDEX.DDF), then you can add a database in the Pervasive Control Center and use that as a query tool.